# Can't resolve all parameters for DataService?

Tags: angular

I am using angular CLI version 1.6.7 and node version 8.9.4
when i am running  `ng serve` it's not give any error.
but when i am trying to package it using `ng build -prod` it's give error

```
``ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for DataService in C:/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/Hocr/project/hocr-ui/src/app/services/data/data.service.ts: (?, [object Object])``
```

below is my data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http/';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private endpoint: string, private http: Http) { }

  getAll() {
    return this.http.get(this.endpoint);
  }

  create( resource ) {
    return this.http.post(this.endpoint, JSON.stringify(resource));
  }

  update( resource ) {
    return this.http.put(this.endpoint + resource.id ,JSON.stringify(resource));
  }

  delete(id) {
    return this.http.delete(this.endpoint + id);
  }
}
```

below is my user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { AppSettings } from '../../app.settings';
import { DataService } from '../data/data.service';

@Injectable()
export class UserService extends DataService {

  constructor(http: Http) {
    super(AppSettings.USER_ENDPOINT, http);
  }
}
```

below is my app.settings.ts

```
export class AppSettings {
    public static API_ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:8080';
    public static USER_ENDPOINT = AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + '/api-user/';
}
```

how can i resolve it ??

Comment: Why are you extending a service instead of declaring inside constructor ?

Comment: Do you have `DataService` in a providers array for any module or have it listed as a type of an injection parameter anywhere?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel yes, I have dataservice in provider array in (app.moudule.ts)

Comment: @AnasIbnNazeer because have lots of services like user, group, roles and i don't want to rewrite my code again and again in each service.

Comment: That is the reason. Angular doesn't know how to create one because that first parameter is a string and it doesn't know what to use for it.

Comment: ohkk..... so can you please tell me how can i resolve this issue beacuse i was trying it from last 12 hous but not getting my mistake... please...

Comment: Are you actually trying to inject a `DataService` anywhere or is it just being extended off of like the `UserService` is doing?

Comment: Does anything actually inject the DataService? If not, try removing the `@injector` and removing it from the providers array. Treat it just like a TypeScript class. (I have NOT tried this ... so don't know if it will solve your issue.) Daniel, looks like we had the same idea at the same time. LOL.

Comment: ohhh got it. thnkss @DanielWStrimpel :-)

Comment: @Injectable() is the issue I think

Comment: If you in fact do need to inject it somewhere, you'll need to create an injection token with the value you want to use, otherwise follow what @DeborahK stated

Comment: @DeborahK thnks

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the `endpoint` to a value provider:

```
export const EndpointToken = new InjectionToken<string>("My Endpoint");

@NgModule({
    ...
    import: [ HttpClientModule ],
    providers: [
        DataService,
        { provide: EndpointToken, useValue: AppSettings.USER_ENDPOINT }
    ]
})
...
```

Then in your `DataService` use the @Inject decorator with the InjectionToken you setup:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(@Inject(EndpointToken) private endpoint: string, private http: Http) { 
  }
  ...
}
```